# Error creating shaded jar: null: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using ASM 6.1 in my project to generate Class files dynamically. But I have a problem when assembling a fat jar.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default-cli) on project uetlx: Error creating shaded jar: null: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.3:shade (default-cli) on project uetlx: Error creating shaded jar: null
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating shaded jar: null
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:540)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.addRemappedClass(DefaultShader.java:415)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shadeSingleJar(DefaultShader.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shadeJars(DefaultShader.java:179)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shade(DefaultShader.java:104)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:454)
        ... 22 more
```

What does it mean? Some confliting `objectweb.asm` version? What is the solution?

Comment: First why are you using such an old version of maven-shade-plugin? Furthermore on which JDK are you running ?

Comment: @khmarbaise The issue turned out to be with the old plugin version as you guessed. Thank you.

Comment: Bumped into the same issue. Upgrading the Maven shade plugin version solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Version 3.1.0 worked for me, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-255

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with version 2.4.3.  Upgrading to the latest version of the plugin (currently 3.2.1) took care of it.

Comment: I had the issue with `3.0.0` upgrading it to `3.2.1` resolved it.

Comment: I had the issue with `3.1.0` when using java 17 and upgraded to `3.3.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: The versions with 2.x seems to be failing when minimizeJar is used along with shade. Versions 3.x seems fine

Answer (score 1):

Just to sort of pile on, the upgrade to the latest version of the plugin also fixed the issue for me. My problem was that the example I had found used the older version and I wasn't thinking about upgrading it, just getting the configuration to solve my issue. Now I will be more conscientious about finding the latest upgrade plus the new configuration.